# Is there some way to use Blade inside a .css file in Laravel to generate a "CSS" view?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am just guessing if this would be possible. 
Sass and Less are very useful when it comes to pre-process css and provide reusability and modularity. Blade does the same with HTML/PHP views.
This would hugely reduce the time required to construct CSS, and to completely avoid (if the developer wants to) Sass/Less.

I have tried to search in the official documentation but I didn't find anything related to this topic. So I'm guessing if there's some way to do it by extending Blade in order to do something like:

```
mystyle.blade.css

@if (dimension('xs') === 1)
 .myclass { color: {$primary-color} }
@else
 .myclass { ... }
@endif
```

and serve this to the browser in the CSS output.

I expect this to work in some way, or at least be able to implement it by extending Blade/Laravel components.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do this with `@component` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots, or with `@push` on a template-by-template basis https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect user agent based on that you can include styles you want.

There is a [package](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent) which is used to detect the agents easily

Install using composer:

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```

If needed, add the service provider in config/app.php:

```
Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider::class
```

And add the Agent facade alias to config/app.php:

```
'Agent' => Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent::class,
```

After installation, pass the user-agent variable from your controller to the desired view.

```
$agent = new Agent();
return view('some.view', compact('agent'));
```

Finally, inside your view, you can check user-agent and load styles according to it:

```
@if($agent->isMobile())
 .myclass { color: {$primary-color} }
@else
 .myclass { ... }
@endif
```